# Disable URL decoding in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I have the following endpoint

```
@RequestMapping("missedcall")
fun missedCall(@RequestParam("v") encryptedValue : String, model: 
ModelMap): String {
    //decrypt encryptedValue here
}
```

When I execute this endpoint with "http://myurl.com/missedcall?v=this+is+my+encrypted+string", encryptedValue initialized as "this is my encrypted string".  I actually want the pluses as they are part of the encryption and I can't decrypt the string without them.

The work around would be URL encode the string back to restore pluses and other special characters, BUT is there a cleaner way?  Maybe disabling URL decoding for this particular endpoint?

Note: I can't pass this param in body, it has to be part of the query string. Also this is written in Kotlin, but I am 100% sure Java has similar issues, so don't feel discouraged by Kotlin :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any web framework will decrypt the query path for you, as that's expected behavior. If that's not what you want, you will have to define a method argument of type HttpServletRequest and parse the query yourself using [`HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SeanPatrickFloyd, implemented it as

```
@RequestMapping("missedcall")
fun missedCall(request: HttpServletRequest, model: ModelMap): String {
    val encodedValue = request.queryString.split("=")[1]
    //decrypt encryptedValue here
}
```